# Single Sign On in GWT Application

Tags: java, gwt, single-sign-on

I want to implement Single Sign On in my GWT Application. 
The situation is, 
When i request http://example.com (parent portal) it is redirecting to login. and when i am loggedin to this system it redirects to homepage where i am loading gwt application. now in that homepage multiple childs are thre in listbox like 1)abc.example.com 2)def.example.com so now if i am selecting abc.example.com then i want to reload the application but with http://abc.example.com without login.

It is like one Parent having multiple childs. when i am logged in to parent it is loading all parent as well as child data and when i am select child it reload all the child data. If it is already loggin from parent it should not ask again for login.

I am using JBoss server.
Thanking You.